# Crypto js not decrypting properly when given wrong AES 256 key

Tags: javascript, react-native, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

Part of my application is using AES 256 to decrypt encrypted string and then pass it to function which checks if decrypted string is correct.

Everything works fine when I give correct key - I get wordArray object with 81 sigBytes. Then I change object to hex and I'm good to go. However, when key is incorrect, returned wordArray has weird negative values of sigBytes and after trying to change it to hex code, I get empty string when in reality I should get 81 bytes of incorrectly decrypted text.

Please note that rest of my application is coded the way that hexKey will be always 32 bytes and iv will be always 16 bytes, so this problem has nothing to do with wrong length of keys.

```
export function decryptAES(enc, hexKey, iv) {
  var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hexKey);
  var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);
  var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    enc,
    key,
    { iv: iv },
    { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC }
  );

  console.log("++++");
  console.log(dec);
  console.log(dec.toString());
  console.log("++++");
  return dec.toString();
}
```

Example output when given correct 32 byte key:

```
    ++++
Object {
  "sigBytes": 81,
  "words": Array [
    1752134516,
    778401904,
    776304752,
    1869505902,
    1949643824,
    909129059,
    808662581,
    909653861,
    1717724773,
    912536165,
    1701012016,
    845308723,
    1667446839,
    825385784,
    1697855799,
    909391927,
    1630822707,
    959669046,
    1664365625,
    962670905,
    856624911,
    252645135,
    252645135,
    252645135,
  ],
}
686f73742e6578702e4578706f6e656e7435343036303563303336353638376566626665366432656563623032626333636338373132633865333937363438376134613339336336633434393961313933
++++
```

Output when 32 byte key is not correct

```
++++
Object {
  "sigBytes": -106,
  "words": Array [
    -1250329685,
    718732109,
    2110917137,
    138597379,
    457610406,
    -1386250595,
    98533977,
    1688834468,
    1693475717,
    -1223868012,
    779204504,
    -893340479,
    1667438189,
    2014283040,
    -1303465345,
    -2113084121,
    1618406295,
    -965279870,
    1579488178,
    -1274259478,
    1900642657,
    340456508,
    -1297174274,
    1109264330,
  ],
}
++++
```

Comment: Is this being executed in browser or in a nodejs environment? I would suggest using the inbuilt [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) library instead if you are in a node environment.

Comment: im using react native with expo

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

To get proper amount of sigBytes regardless if key is good or not, simply add NoPadding. With NoPadding CFB, CTR, or OFB mode is required.

Example implementation:

```
  var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(enc, key, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
  });
```